# Why are the UINTX_C() macros not properly defined in Windows stdint.h?

Tags: c++, macros, windows-7-x64, language-lawyer

In MVSC, when I `#include <stdint.h>`, I end up with the following definitions for the UINTX_C and INTX_C macros:

```
#define INT8_C(x)   (x)
#define INT16_C(x)  (x)
#define INT32_C(x)  ((x) + (INT32_MAX - INT32_MAX))

#define UINT8_C(x)  (x)
#define UINT16_C(x) (x)
#define UINT32_C(x) ((x) + (UINT32_MAX - UINT32_MAX))
```

Clearly the 8 and 16-bit macros just pass through the constant unmodified, which doesn't exactly perform what they are designed to do.  Is there a different file to include on Windows to get the proper definitions?

Comment: In C++, you have int8_t , int16_t , int32_t , uint8_t , uint16_t , uint32_t . You don't need macros

Comment: @amchacon, C has those, too.

Comment: MSVC's C99 support is notoriously incomplete. I'd wager this just hasn't been worth it for them to fix. STL does say that the C99 standard library support is complete apart from tgmath.h in the VS2015 preview, though, so I'm not sure what these guarantee if that claim is accurate.

Comment: @chris insofar as the compiler implements the behavior I don't believe these are non-conforming.

Comment: @amchacon Agreed.  And my work-around is to use static_cast<uint8_t>().  However, these macros are nice for specifying constants (which shouldn't need casting) without worrying about whether to use 'u' or 'uL' to get the correct number of bits.

Comment: @Mgetz, C99 says "The macro INTN_C(value) shall expand to an integer constant expression corresponding to the type int_leastN_t.". VS expands `INT8_C(5)` to an `int`, while `int_least8_t` is `signed char`, so it would seem non-conforming. As far as I know, C++11 references C99 for this.

Comment: @chris: In this context, "corresponding to" doesn't mean it's the same type. There's a bug in the C99 standard, corrected in N1256 and C11. The type of `INT8_C(5)` is the type of `int_least8_t` *after the integer promotions* (i.e., `int`). This is necessary because there is no syntax for integer constants of types narrower than `int`.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I saw. Thanks for the definitive information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I can tell, they are defined correctly.

The macros expand to integer constant expressions *corresponding to* the specified types, not *of* the specified types.

Neither C nor C++ has a syntax for integer constant expressions of types narrower than `int`. It depends on implicit conversions to convert `int` expressions to narrower types where needed.

(C++ includes the contents of the C header `<stdint.h>` by reference to the C standard. The latest C++ standard refers to the 1999 C standard. I'm not sure what the status of the three C99 Technical Corrigenda is with respect to C++.)

Looking at [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.20.4p1:

> The following function-like macros expand to integer constants
>   suitable for initializing objects that have integer types
>   corresponding to types defined in **`<stdint.h>`**. Each macro name
>   corresponds to a similar type name in 7.20.1.2 or 7.20.1.5.

And in paragraph 3:

> The type of the expression shall have the same type as would an
>   expression of the corresponding type *converted according to the
>   integer promotions*.

(emphasis added)

For example, `int_least8_t` is likely to be a typedef for `signed char`. If so, it makes sense (and is conforming) to have a definition like:

```
#define INT8_C(x)   (x)
```

N1570 is a draft of the 2011 ISO C standard. The 1999 ISO C standard (C99) actually had a bug in this area. It states, in 7.18.4.1p2, that, for example, `INT8_C(`*value*`)` expands to a signed integer constant with the specified
value and type `int_least8_t`. This is not possible in general (without compiler extensions) because C has no syntax for integer constants of types narrower than `int` (and a cast can't be used because the result has to be usable in a `#if` expression -- though that requirement wasn't in the original C99 standard). The [first Technical Corrigendum](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/9899tc1/n32071.PDF) corrected this, in response to [Defect Report # 209](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_209.htm), to say that the type is the corresponding type *converted according to the
integer promotions*. The corrected text is in the [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) draft of C99 and in the published C11 standard.

Comment: Having a macro with the definition you reference doesn't seem to be particularly useful

Comment: @KyleL here's one use that comes to mind: `bool is_set(uint64_t var, int bit) { return !!(var & (UINT64_C(1) << bit)); }` .  Without the macro this would break on 32-bit int system.

Comment: @KyleL: By itself, no -- but it's one of a collection of macros for all the supported widths (8, 16, 32, and 64 bits, and possibly more). Some but not all of these will be no-ops. By defining them all, programmers don't have to worry about how they're defined.

Comment: So is there a way to define a constant for uint8_t or uint16_t that is guaranteed to have those specific types in a portable fashion?

Comment: @KyleL: No, there isn't. Why would you need such a constant? A constant of type `int` will be implicitly converted by any of assignment, initialization, argument passing, or return.

Comment: @KeithThompson I have an overloaded function that accepts uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, etc.  Without specifying the constant type the compiler warns about an ambiguous function call.  I guess static_cast will have to work around it.

Comment: @KyleL: `static_cast<uint8_t>(value)`

Comment: By the way, MSVC actually implements such an extension. It supports the integer suffixes `i{8,16,32,64}`, but only `i64` is officially documented (it was implemented before `LL` / `long long`). The oddity (or even a bug) is the type of `0i8` which is `__int8` / `char` and not `signed char` / `int8_t`!